# Using Interfaces to design an application

Tags: php, oop, interface, abstract-class

I am trying to implement a [Short Message Service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS) or as you call it Texting service for mobiles into my PHP application that will send sms to my customers using various SMS providers (the real case senario is diff but here I am trying my best to explain my question, so pls bear with this SMS example only).

Now, I am told to follow design patterns (not sure which one as I am new to patterns) to integrate it.

My SMS class should have the following methods

```
<?php
class Verizon
{
        public function __construct($apiKey){
                // class constructor code...
        }

        public function AddNumber(array $numbers)
        {
                // ...
        }

        public function Send()
        {
                // ...
        }
}
```

Now, just like a verizon, i will have different providers in future like AT&T, Cellcom, T-Mobile US etc...

So here are the questions:

Q1. Is it really a good idea to have a different class for different  providers? Means If i need to implement a new provider, I have to write a new class? If no, then what?

Q2. How do I make use of interfaces in this case? (i am told to use interfaces)

Q3. If you could please draft me a skeleton of the structure of the best way to implement with an interface, i will really appreciate that.

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

> Q1. Is it really a good idea to have a different class for different providers? Means If i need to implement a new provider, I have to write a new class? If no, then what?

Yes, this is a good way to approach the problem.  All providers should support the same basic set of operations, so an interface would help you abstract the provider-specific details away from the rest of the application.

> Q2. How do I make use of interfaces in this case? (i am told to use interfaces)

For simple SMS, something this simple would probably be fine:

```
interface ISMSProvider
{
    public function sendSMS($number, $message);
}
```

I'd consider writing implementations so that `$number` could be a single number or an array of numbers.  Then your provider objects are *stateless* (you don't need `AddNumber()` etc.; all information is passed in the arguments).

> Q3. If you could please draft me a skeleton of the structure of the best way to implement with an interface, i will really appreciate that.

Given the above interface, you would write an implementation something like this:

```
class VerizonSMSProvider implements ISMSProvider
{
    // Add a constructor if you need to provide variable details such as API
    // endpoint or API key.

    public function sendSMS($number, $message)
    {
        // Actual implementation here.
    }
}
```

Comment: sms is 'global' so why a class per provider? and there are thousands of them globally?

Comment: @Dagon Because then you can swap out the implementation; the code doesn't have to bind to a specific provider.  For example, you might have a function that, given a phone number, returns the provider to use for that phone number.  Then the calling code doesn't have to care what provider it is, as long as it can send SMS messages.  (You could even have a meta-provider that will iterate the number list and delegate to each specific provider.)

Comment: @Dagon (And even if you only have one provider globally, this allows you to swap out the implementation without much fuss if you switch providers.)

Comment: @cdhowie Thanks for the reply. I have another situation. Suppose to use all those different providers I have to use their API library, which i have to include/autoload somewhere, instantiate their class and depending on what sms provider it is, i will use the api library of that provider. Where do I add those library and where to do the IF ELSE conditions to load the third party api lib?